# xslt loop to add numbers

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following xml.

```
<employee>
    <record id=1>
      <fname>mark</fname>
      <lname>smith</lname>
      <id>10</id>
    <record id=2>
     ........
 </employee>
```

I want to add id for each record and get the total.

i do not know exect number of record that i have under the employee. it could be 1 or 10 or 100.

i found following example from one of the forum. I can use that but is their a simpler way to achieve this?

```
<xsl:call-template name="for.loop">
 <xsl:with-param name="i">1</xsl:with-param>
 <xsl:with-param name="count">10</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
<!-- Rename "old name" elements to "new name" -->
<xsl:template name="for.loop">
 <xsl:param name="i"/>
 <xsl:param name="count"/>
 <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $count">
<!--    body of the loop goes here    -->
 </xsl:if>
 <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $count">
  <xsl:call-template name="for.loop">
    <xsl:with-param name="i">
    <!-- Increment index-->
    <xsl:value-of select="$i + 1"/>
   </xsl:with-param>
   <xsl:with-param name="count">
    <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
   </xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your data is not well-formed XML (no quotes around attributes), and you haven't made it clear whether you want to sum the id attributes or the id elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `sum` function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <total>
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(/employee/record/id)"/>
    </total>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```